# Get user role/permissions for authenticated user Gmail API - PHP SDK

Tags: php, gmail-api, google-workspace

I am trying to get the role of an email (is it a super admin) with this `PHP` code:

```
$email = 'an email with the same domain';
$credentials_file = '../service-account.json';
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='.$credentials_file);

// Initialize Google Client
$client = new Google_Client();

$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
// scopes to change signature
$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile']);

// Initialize Gmail
$gmail = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
// set signature
$signature = new Google_Service_Gmail_SendAs();
// update signature
```

I am using latest `PHP SDK`. The email is always with the same domain as the super administrator email, but he/she is not always a super admin.

What I have tried is:

```
var_dump($gmail->users->getProfile($email));
```

, but I am getting an error:

> failedPrecondition,
>       message: Bad Request"

I read from here - [Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/getProfile), that I need one of listed permissions and I have `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly`, which I have added to Google admin console for super admin user.

How can I get the role of the user email which is with the same domain ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [the PHP API client docs](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#authentication-with-service-accounts), you need to add `$client->setSubject($email)` before calling `new Google_Service_Gmail($client)`, because you need to impersonate the user before calling Gmail API.